# Mangoldt Lambda Sum Rearrangement (from proof of Logarithmic Derivative of Riemann zeta function)

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Also, we have by the definition of Λ,

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \Lambda(n) n^{−s} = \sum_p(\log p) \sum_{n \geq 1}p^{−ns}$$

(From https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithmic_Derivative_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function)

This step is apparently so trivial that it needn't be included in the proof, but I cannot work out how it works. I know that it's a relatively straightforward step, but I have no idea...

Comment: What is the definition of $\Lambda(n)$? What happens if you plug the definition into the left-hand side?

Comment: Λ(n) is the Mangoldt lambda function, defined as ln(p) for n a prime power, and 0 otherwise. The only definition I know of is: ln(lcm(1,...,n))=sum(Λ(n))[n,m<n], which I have tried using but can't find any way of solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\Lambda(n)$ is zero unless $n$ is a prime power $p^m$, 
we can only worry about prime powers, and sum over these instead.
So (assuming the sum converges at all), we have
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \Lambda(n) n^{-s} =
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}} \sum_{m \geq 1} \Lambda(p^m) (p^m)^{-s} = 
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}} \sum_{m \geq 1} (\log p) p^{-ms} = 
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}}(\log p) \sum_{m \geq 1} p^{-ms}.
$$
Now make the (unfortunate) substitution of the dummy variable $n$ for $m$ on the right, and you get the claimed formula.

Comment: Perfect, lifesaver! Thank you very much. I was missing that first step of only summing over the prime powers.

Comment: Absolutely. Glad to help.